# Why this behaviour of ==, when object is creates by boxing in java?

Tags: java

```
class G2 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
 Short u = 127;
 Short v = 127;
 System.out.println(u==v);
 System.out.println(u!=v);
 Short u1 = 129;
 Short v1 = 129;
 System.out.println(u1==v1);
 System.out.println(u1!=v1);
}
}
```

I know that when range is between -128 to 127 == operator matches content or value inside object otherwise object reference code is matched of two objects. Why this kind of implementation is there in JAVA?

Comment: Provide the output please

Comment: Output is: `true false false true`.

Comment: Try this link :http://bishtprashant.blogspot.com/2011/11/why-two-integer-objects-are-not-equal.html

Answer (score 4):

Auto-boxing implicitly calls [Short.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#valueOf%28short%29), which uses cached box instances for small numbers up to 127.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` objects with internal value in the range between -128 and 127 are compared with an interned object of the same type and value, therefore a reference comparison yields `true`.

Ideally, every such comparison would yield `true`, but it is not feasible in practice to keep an object for every possible integer, that's why the Java standard doesn't demand it beyond that point.